# What is the reasoning behind 1 ISA subscription per type per tax year

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

I get that, in each tax year, you can pay-in up to your ISA limit (at the moment £20000) into any number of - or create new - ISA accounts, so long as it's only *one* of *each* type. So you can create a Cash ISA and a Stocks & Shares ISA, and pay into a Lifetime ISA all in the same year, as long as the total contribution does not exceed £20000. What I'd like to understand is, what's the rational behind only allowing contributions for *one* of each type per tax year?

As an example, say I hold two Stocks & Shares ISAs. One is managed by me, and I decide what stocks go in, and the other is managed by a bank (i.e. a Managed Fund). Even if I were to stay within the limit, I can't put money into both in the same year, even though that obviously has benefits wrt to risk management.

I really can't think of a reason why this restriction is in place, and it would make more sense if the restriction was only paying into *one* of *any* type during one year. Can anyone explain why this is the way it is?

Comment: These rules were thought up by politicians.  "Making sense" rarely seems to be high on their list of priorities.

Comment: Bear in mind that cash and stocks-and-shares ISAs used to be even more separate than they are currently, but the concepts were somewhat - but not fully - merged in 2014: https://www.whatinvestment.co.uk/stocks-and-shares-isas-and-cash-isas-merged-with-new-15000-annual-allowance-2458162/

Comment: " say I hold two Stocks & Shares ISAs. One is managed by me, and I decide what stocks go in, and the other is managed by a bank (i.e. a Managed Fund). " seems to be not right - a S&S ISA is an envelope that the holder puts *money* into, and what happens to the money within is always entirely up to the holder. Whether the money is used to buy individual stocks, or a managed fund, either way it's the holder that decides. You can't just instruct a bank to run your S&S ISA for you.

Comment: @AakashM Yeah, I know. I just was illustrating two different ways you might want to use a S&S ISA, one where you manage the _investment_ yourself and one where the _specifics_ of the investment is managed by the bank/fund

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm speculating, but I suspect this is intended to ease administration for HMRC and the banks (etc) holding the ISAs.

The main fore-runner of the ISA was the [TESSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax-exempt_special_savings_account), which had a very simple requirement: everybody over 18 was entitled to a single TESSA. To open an account, they would supply their National Insurance number, which could easily be checked against a central list to see if they already had a TESSA open. The bank holding that TESSA could then directly check if you were within the deposit limits.

When ISAs replaced TESSAs and PEPs in 1999, things got a bit more complicated: there was a limit of "subscribing to" one Cash ISA and one Stocks and Shares ISA per year, which could be checked easily, but as you point out the *deposit allowance* could be shared between those two ISAs. This presumably requires more co-ordination, updating HMRC with your total balance to make sure it doesn't exceed the limit.

If you could "subscribe to" any number of accounts, this co-ordination would increase: you could set direct debits paying £100 per week into 20 accounts, and after 10 weeks, they would all need to be notified by HMRC to refuse further deposits because you'd used your allowance - but only once HMRC had received all the reports of what you *had* deposited and added them up.